# How to Add Two toolbar Manager into Coolbar or any other alternatives?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, toolbar, rcp

I have two views View1 and View2
set1 toolbar items are common for both the views and set2 toolbar items should be displayed only in view2 along with set1.

I am using menu contribution feature of eclipse. I have created two location URIs
toolbar:com.omg.views.Objects.custom --> which has common items 
toolbar:com.omg.views.Objects.custom1 --> which is needed only for View2.

I tried following:

```
CoolBar coolBar = new CoolBar(toolBarComposite, SWT.NONE);
GridData gridData1 = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
coolBar.setLayoutData(gridData1);
CoolBarManager coolManager = new CoolBarManager(SWT.DEFAULT);


IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService)                             
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
        .getService(IMenuService.class);
manager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
menuService.populateContributionManager(manager,
        "toolbar:com.omg.views.Objects.custom"); //$NON-NLS-1$
manager.createControl(coolBar);
manager.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER,    
true, false));

manager1 = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
menuService.populateContributionManager(manager1,
        "toolbar:com.omg.views.Objects.custom1"); //$NON-NLS-1$
manager1.createControl(coolBar);
manager1.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, 
 SWT.CENTER, true, false));

coolManager.add(manager);
coolManager.add(manager1);
coolManager.createControl(toolBarComposite);
coolManager.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, 
SWT.CENTER, true, false));
```

unfortunately above code did not work for me, It would be great if I get some suggestion.